# Where to start GeoServer Development?

Tags: geoserver, development

I want to contribute to GeoServer development. I am well experienced in programming and since I am now completely working on GIS projects, I think I will find enough time for these tasks.

Where should I start? Are there to do lists or tasks for developers? Are there basic jobs for beginners?

What would you suggest?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/index.html ????

Comment: actually i was expecting your comments about subject

Comment: It would be nice if you do some research and ask a more specific question about a concrete problem, you will get better results. Here is a guide about good practices: http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: As a beginner, I met the same problems with you. Could you tell me how you start to learn Geoserver development? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not an answer. It should rather be a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding "basic jobs for beginners", we don't have such a list but have a look at jira.codehaus.org and look into bug reports, it might take some time but you should find something easy enough to look it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [Developers' Guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/)? Once you can build GeoServer on a local machine (this is harder than it looks) check out http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/policies/index.html to see what needs doing.